# Java on integers , srtrings and doubles

Tags: java, string, int, boolean

So I am practicing for a highschool competition over the weekend and I am having trouble figuring out why this question returns **False False**

```
String str = "12"; 
Integer num = new Integer(12); 
Double val = new Double(12.0); 
System.out.print(str.equals(num)); 
System.out.print(" " + num.equals(val));
```

Answer (score 3):

if you take a look at `equals` method of `String` and `Integer` classes you'll see the why:

**String.equals:**

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

**Integer.equals:**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
}
return false;
}
```

as you see because all `12` , `"12"` and `12.2` are `instances of different classes` so the `equals` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are *different types* with same value. `"12"` is not equal to `12` .

i.e, `"12"` , `12` and `12.0` are 3 different *types*.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are creating 3 new objects, and Java is a language based on references, and this 3 lines :

```
String str = "12"; 
Integer num = new Integer(12); 
Double val = new Double(12.0);
```

So the first time u should understand, it's you are creating 3 new objects here.

The Second is to check what the equals method do in every Class.
For the First Class

```
System.out.print(str.equals(num));
```

In this line you are calling the equals method from String class, So if go to check the method in the String class, u will see this:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String) anObject;
            int n = value.length;
            if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = 0;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                            return false;
                    i++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So the first thing that u should notice here is there are only two possibilities that this method return true:
the first one is, both objects are pointing to the same reference, it means u do something like this:

```
String str = "12";
String strb = str;
```

and the second one is Object passed as a reference would be a String class, thing that never happen.
because in this line:

```
System.out.print(str.equals(num));
```

you are sending a Integer as Parameter. so the second case is never happen.

For the next case:

```
System.out.print(" " + num.equals(val));
```

You should analize the equals method in the Integer class, and u should see something like this:

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here as u see, the only way this method check the possibility to return true, it's the case where u send a Integer as a parameter.(it means a reference from the Integer class).

I hope, it can be helpful for u.
Greetings.

Comment: `there are only two possibilities that this method return true` Your two cases are interesting, since they don't care about the value of both objects.